# Passing authentication through a service

Tags: security, authentication

I have the following systems

```
A [user's client device]  <--->  B [my server]  <--->  C [user's private server]
```

All the relevant software is under my control. My server *B* does not store user data, but needs to generate reports using the data from the user's private server *C*.

I'd like my server *B* to be unable to access the user's server *C* except while doing it under the client *A*'s request. The client *A*, however, is unable to access their server *C* directly except through my server (B).

How do I create an authentication scheme where all data between *A* and *C* is passed through *B*, but *B* is unable to later impersonate *A*?

*Notes:*

- The underlying assumptions are that *C* is secured (because *B*'s access to it is extremely strict and it is inaccessible from t eh internet), but *B* could possibly be compromised. So even if *B* is compromised, I'd only like the attackers to be able to access data that had passed through it while it was compromised, but no more than that.
- *B* needs to run reports about the data, so it can't just all be encrypted on *C* and decrypted on *A*.
- *C* is connected to the internet, but through a VPN service which completely isolates it excepting a few specific connections, one of which being the connection to *B*.
- *A* could be any user device - say their phone or browser - so a solution which can be implemented with HTML would be a plus, though I can't think of one. I'm okay with using a JavaScript solution or even, if needed, requiring client software (i.e. a phone app or Windows application).

Comment: My initial thoughts are to run a challenge-response authentication for each request, but (1) I'm no security expert, so I'm not sure how much running multiple requests could compromise the password and (2) it seems like large overhead because each request would have to make two round trips.

Comment: Seems like there a few holes in this spec. 1) Do you care if B can see the data being passed back to A? 2) What information needs to be available to reports, doesn't that defeat the point? -- If 1 is true, the response needs to be encrypted, and if 2 is unlimited, then all of this attempt at privacy is moot.

Comment: @RussellLeggett: 1 is false; _B_ _has_ to see the data unencrypted. 2 is unlimited, and like I mentioned if _B_ was compromised the attackers would be able to access data that had passed through it, but what's important to me is that they wouldn't be able to forge new requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have A post S/MIME messages digitally signed with a non-repudiation certificate to B; B can validate the signature, examine the contents, and log information for reporting before forwarding the signed message to C. When C receives a message with a valid signature, it executes the instructions in the message. These messages could be transported over HTTPS to provide privacy from everyone else, or A could encrypt it at the S/MIME layer with B's certificate, and B would just pass the decrypted-but-signed content to C.

Alternatively, you could use a NULL cipher suite and client authentication on an SSL connection between A and C, with B snooping the un-encrypted traffic as a man-in-the-middle. This would probably require custom coding for B, in order to extract application data from the SSL records, and B would not be able to verify integrity of the traffic (C would, however, because it would have negotiated the necessary key with A).

Both of these approaches rely on the client, A, using a certificate (or a trusted public key, if you use PGP instead of S/MIME).

Comment: S/MIME would mean signing the request with a certificate, am I correct? How is this different than a secret key shared between _A_ and _C_, as Russell suggest below?

Comment: @configurator This uses public key crypto, while S3 uses a shared key; that can simplify key management in a lot of scenarios. Also, it allows B to verify requests, which it can't do with a shared secret. This could be an issue if an attacker might want to corrupt B's logs. It provides security at the message level (security at rest), rather than coupled with the transport. That opens opportunities for asynchronous communication, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Could you use some kind of single use or revokable tokens? Full auth is never given to B from A, but instead A gives B one time tokens. You could use a secret key that only A and C know to enable A to generate new tokens. You can actually look at Amazon S3 auth for a good example of this.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/MakingRequests.html

Basically, when A makes a request, it creates a temporary signing token which would let B act on its behalf. Amazon even lets you constrain what actions that token can authorize.

Comment: So basically, digitally sign the request, including a timestamp in it, and don't respond to requests which aren't signed correctly or have a stale timestamp. Simple, and prevents spoofing. Thanks!